# Can I convert user input language to default collation of database?

Tags: mysql, collation

I want to search user input in my database. database collation is `latin1_swedish_ci`. I don't want to change that, instead can I change user input `utf-8` to `latin1_swedish_ci`?

Edit:
I approach two methods.
Method 1: I imported and used default collation `latin1_swedish_ci` and character set `latin1`. Then I have
 [image]

Here I can query like `SELECT * FROM dict WHERE english_word = '$_value'` and I get all the values of column including malayalam_definition in the browser as desired. But problem is I can't query like `SELECT * FROM dict WHERE malayalam_definition = '$_value'`. It returns no result.

Method 2: I changed collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` and character set to `utf8`. Then in mysql I get desired values like
[image]
Here I when I query like `SELECT * FROM dict WHERE english_word = '$_value'` **in browser** I get question marks in `malayalam_definition` values like
[image]

Result of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character\_set\_%';`

```
+--------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name            | Value  |
+--------------------------+--------+
| character_set_client     | utf8   |
| character_set_connection | utf8   |
| character_set_database   | utf8   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary |
| character_set_results    | utf8   |
| character_set_server     | latin1 |
| character_set_system     | utf8   |
+--------------------------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Do I need to change `character_set_server`, then how to do it?

Comment: "instead can I change user input utf-8 to latin1_swedish_ci" No you shouldn't it's generally not a great idea to convert `utf8` to `latin1` simply because `utf8` does support more then `latin1` does so you can get corrupted data.

Comment: letme try, Is it possible?

Comment: `character_set_server = latin1` is not the villain.  See the Edit to my Answer.  How did you do the "import"?  `LOAD DATA` has a charset clause in it; what did you say?  `mysqldump` sets the charset in the file; what did it say?

Comment: I used this command to load data `load data local infile '/mnt/c/Users/justi/Desktop/enml/file.csv' 
into table dict 
fields terminated by '\t' 
IGNORE 1 LINES;`

Comment: `SET NAMES utf8` Worked for me, now showing correct character in the browser and phpmyadmin. Still I can't search for the malayalam_definition column like `SELECT * FROM dict WHERE malayalam_definition = '$_value'` giving empty result

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the "database collation" is only a default.  The real question is what is the `CHARACTER SET` of the *columns* that you are interested in.

Then, what are the bytes in your *client*?  Are they encoded as `latin1`?  Or `utf8`?  In either case, tell MySQL that that is what is coming at it.  This is preferably done in the connection parameters.  (What is your client language?)  Alternatively, use `SET NAMES latin1` or `SET NAMES utf8`, according to the client encoding.

Now, what MySQL will do on `INSERT` and `SELECT`...  It will *convert* the encoding from the client's encoding to the column's encoding as you do an `INSERT`.  No further action is needed to achieve this.

Similarly, MySQL will convert the other way during a `SELECT`.

(Of course, if the column and the client are talking the same encoding, no "convert" is needed.)

Your question mentions "collation".  So far, I have only talked about `CHARACTER SETs`, also known as "encoding".  Contrast with that, the sorting and comparing of two strings -- this is `COLLATION`.

For the `CHARACTER SET` `latin1`, the default `COLLATION` is `latin1_swedish_ci`.
For the `CHARACTER SET` `utf8`, the default `COLLATION` is `utf8_general_ci`.
There are several different "collations" to handle the quirks of German or Turkish or Spanish or (etc) orderings.

Please explain *why* you are trying to do what you stated.  There are many ways you can do it *wrong*, so I do not want to give you an `ALTER` statement -- it may just make things worse for the *real* goal.

It is better to use utf8mb4 instead of utf8.  The outside world refers to `UTF-8`; this is equivalent to MySQL's `utf8mb4`.

**Edit** (after OP's Edit)

The first screenshot shows "Mojibake".  Another screenshot shows question marks.  The causes of each are covered in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Comment: Thanks @Rick James for detailed answer, I have edited my question.